# Magento2 Special Price is not correctly reflecting on Product List Page and Search Page

Tags: magento2, varnish, special-price, msi

**Pr-conditions:**

Magento version: Magento Commerce 2.3.6

Varnish version : 5.2.1

PHP version: PHP 7.2.33

MySQL version: 5.7

Multi Website architecture
Catalog Price Scope = "Website" (Admin > Stores > Configuration > Catalog > Catalog > Price > Catalog Price Scope = Website )
MSI is also enabled per website scope

**Steps to reproduce:**

1. Go to Admin > System > Import and import the product special price using a CSV file
2. Under Admin Catalog > Products > Search for a particular product > change teh scope to "Website" level > Price > Advanced Price > make sure special price is reflecting correctly
3. Go to Admin > System > Cache Management > "Flush Magento Cache"
4. Go to frontend > particular website > Product detail page > make sure special price is reflecting correctly (works as expected)
5. Go to frontend > particular website > Product List page (Category page) > make sure special price is reflecting correctly (special price is incorrect)
6. Go to frontend > particular website > Search for the product with SKU> Search Result page > make sure special price is reflecting correctly (special price is incorrect)

**Expected Result:**

Show correct special price on the Detail page, Category Page, Search Result Page

**Actual Result:**

Correct special price is shown on Product Detail page but Not on category or search result page

**Please note this issue only appearing on Production, issue not reproducing on Staging/UAT and local environments**

Great if someone can assist on this. Thanks..

Comment: please change to default luma theme and check it showing or not?

Comment: Thanks, @GohilRajesh for the reply, but this solution didn't work